# Use mobile charger as power suppy to ESP8266 wifi module with 3.3v converter

Tags: esp8266, electronics, ftdi

I am using this FTDI connector to power and flash code inside ESP8266 module.

[image: I am using this FTDI connector to power and flash code inside ESP8266 module.]

Now I am done with adding code to ESP8266, now I just want to power it.
but when I connect the mobile charger(5v output) instead of FTDI connect it gives only "?????? ???? ????" this output.
can't I use this as VCC and GND ??

Comment: If you've replaced the FTDI with a mobile charger, where are you seeing this output?

Comment: I am only replacing vcc and GND, Rx and Tx are as it is connected to FTDI.

Comment: But not GND to the FTDI board...? Where is your circuit then? How can electrons flow...?